# Can I create a workflow without tasks?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

For my customized workflow created in SharePoint Designer 2013 is it possible for me to not have an associated Task list. Having a task list is just adding confusion for the user and causing more headaches for my customization.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have to be tied to a tasks list, but you don't have to actually use any tasks in your workflow. If you are planning on doing any sort of approval or feedback process, then it will use the associated task list. If you aren't using these things, it won't touch the list, but you still have to associate it with one.

Comment: thanks that is what I thought but I was hoping for complete disconnect but I think I can make that whole process hidden for the users.

Comment: correction, my core question is already posted.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161525/sharepoint-designer-custom-email-workflow-2013